# How can I use current datetime as parameters in a power bi query statement for REST API?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

How can I use current datetime as parameters in a power bi query statement for REST API? I specified two parameters "DateStart" and "DateEnd" which I want to include in my Data source's SQL statement,i want to add DateEnd as current system datetime & DateStart as 15 min past datetime.

my query is

```
let
   body = Text.ToBinary("{
      ""Type"": ""Feedbacks"",
      ""FromDate"": ""01-01-2015 23:00:00.000"",
      ""ToDate"": ""20-09-2017 23:00:00.000"",
      ""SearchField"": ""test"",
      ""SearchFieldValue"": ""*""
}"),
   actualUrl = "http:/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/service/GetSomething",
   options = [
      Headers =[#"Content-type"="application/json"],
      Content=body
   ],
   result = Web.Contents(actualUrl, options),
    #"Imported JSON" = Json.Document(result,65001)
in
    #"Imported JSON"
```

Here i want to add end date as current datetime & start date as current-15 min

Thanks in advance.